# "took advantage of" or exploit

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Suddenly, three cats went out from behind the trash bins, the black, the white and the gray.
>
> Ray tried to run away, but the three cats surrounded him.
>
> "What a little mouse," said the black cat.
>
> "What a brown, little mouse,"  muttered the white cat.
>
> "What a coward, brown little mouse," shouted the gray cat.
>
> The three cats started laughing. Ray **took advantage of** their laughing and run away to his small hole.

Is *took advantage of* properly used in the above? or should I replace it with another word (e.g. exploit)?

**Update:**

I think this expression (took advantage of) doesn't used properly in the above statement because (as appear in the below definition) sometimes it has bad intentions meaning. and Ray don't has bad intentions, He just want to escape.

> take advantage of sth: 
>   1. to use the good things in a situation.
>   2. to treat someone **badly** in order to get something good from them

Comment: The entire example has problems, not just the highlighted part. We do not proofread, but yes, the highlighted part is fine.

Comment: no need to proofread, I'm studying English, and I wrote it to practice. just I'm asking about if I understand "took advantage of" expression in right way. thank you

Comment: "in **right** way, sorry -- write means to make the phrase, **right** means correct.  (I hope you do not mind the correction.)

Comment: I think I fix it faster than your comment, anyway thank you agian

Comment: if I mind the correction, why am I asking question in this forum. :)

Comment: Word. Ha! Good point but some do mind.  So here I go  ag**ai**n. question**s**. :wink:  The teacher in me needs to be reminded to stay in retirement!

Comment: Writing advice (as a literary editor): Ray took that as his cue and scampered away or off to his hole. Is Ray a mouse? :) Took advantage of is ***much too heavy*** here.

Comment: Sorry, I read it too fast, he was there. :)

Comment: You have added two definitions. definition 1 relates to taking advantage of a situation and definition 2 relates to taking advantage of a person.  **their laughing** is a situation not a person, so definition 1 applies: it does not have negative connotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, **I can't resist**:

Suddenly, three cats **came out or sauntered out** from behind the trash bins, one black, one white and one gray.

Ray tried to run away but the three cats surrounded him.

"What a teeny mouse," exclaimed the black cat.

"What a teeny brown mouse," muttered the white cat.

"What a cowardly little mouse," shouted the gray cat.

The three cats started laughing. Ray took that as his cue and scampered off to his tiny hole.

Comment: I was itching to do that!

Comment: :) I know since you mentioned retirement and teaching. :)

Comment: @Lambie Thank you, Could I ask why you change "little" with "teeny",  "little mouse" is more common in kids stories (I read some of them). Is "teeny" fit with the context more than "little" ?http://www.kidsworldfun.com/shortstories_lionandmouse.php

Comment: To be more creative, that's all.